# Could not make Json Request body from Iphone

Tags: iphone, json, http-post, wcf-rest

I am a .Net Software developer .I have Created a WCF Rest API for User Validation Following is its signature.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "/Validate", Method = "POST")]
    UserListResponse ValidateUser(Login obj);
```

It is working fine in fiddler with following Request Body

```
{"Username":"admin",Password:"111"}
```

My problem is, it is not accessible from Iphone using http post method but it is working fine in Android Http post method.

Following are my Code :

```
NSError *theError = nil;

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Username", @"Password", nil];

NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"admin", @"111", nil];

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSString *myJSONString =[jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];

NSData *myJSONData =[myJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"myJSONString :%@", myJSONString); 

NSLog(@"myJSONData :%@", myJSONData); 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.192/ShopMonkeyService/ShopMonkey.svc/Validate"]];

[request setHTTPBody:myJSONData]; 

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];   

NSLog(@"response : %@", theResponse);

NSLog(@"error : %@", theError);

NSLog(@"data : %@", data);

NSMutableString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"string: %@", string);

NSDictionary *jsonDictionaryResponse = [string JSONValue];

NSLog(@"dic: %@", jsonDictionaryResponse);
```

Following are my response Error :

> 2012-07-06 11:49:04.201 ShopMonkey[524:207] -JSONRepresentation
>   failed. Error trace is: (null)
>
> 2012-07-06 11:49:04.201 ShopMonkey[524:207] myJSONString
>   :{"Password":"111","Username":"admin"}
>
> 2012-07-06 11:49:04.201 ShopMonkey[524:207] myJSONData :<7b225061
>   7373776f 7264223a 22313131 222c2255 7365726e 616d6522 3a226164
>   6d696e22 7d>
>
> 2012-07-06 11:51:13.312 ShopMonkey[524:207] response : (null)
>
> 2012-07-06 11:51:13.312 ShopMonkey[524:207] error : Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."
>   UserInfo=0x6041370
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.192/ShopMonkeyService/ShopMonkey.svc/Validate,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.192/ShopMonkeyService/ShopMonkey.svc/Validate,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x6043a90 "The network connection was lost."}
>
> 2012-07-06 11:51:13.312 ShopMonkey[524:207] data : (null)
>
> 2012-07-06 11:51:13.313 ShopMonkey[524:207] string:
>
> 2012-07-06 11:51:13.313 ShopMonkey[524:207] -JSONValue failed. Error
>   trace is: (
>
> ```
> "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=11 \"Unexpected end of string\" UserInfo=0x6041b90 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected
> ```
>
> end of string}"
>
> )
>
> 2012-07-06 11:51:13.313 ShopMonkey[524:207] dic: (null)

Can anyone point me out what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance
vijay

see my error details vivek

Error Details:

2012-07-06 16:54:37.416 ShopMonkey[1895:40b] -[CJSONSerializer serializeDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c03740

2012-07-06 16:54:37.417 ShopMonkey[1895:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CJSONSerializer serializeDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c03740'

*** Call stack at first throw:

(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00ec2be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010175c2 objc_exception_throw + 47

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00ec46fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187

3   CoreFoundation                      0x00e34366 ***forwarding*** + 966

4   CoreFoundation                      0x00e33f22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50

5   ShopMonkey                          0x000030c5 -[ShopMonkeyViewController signinbtnclick] + 425

6   UIKit                               0x0034fa6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119

7   UIKit                               0x003de1b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67

8   UIKit                               0x003e0647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527

9   UIKit                               0x003df1f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458

10  UIKit                               0x003740d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567

11  UIKit                               0x0035537a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447

12  UIKit                               0x0035a732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576

13  GraphicsServices                    0x0177ca36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550

14  CoreFoundation                      0x00ea4064 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52

15  CoreFoundation                      0x00e046f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215

16  CoreFoundation                      0x00e01983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979

17  CoreFoundation                      0x00e01240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208

18  CoreFoundation                      0x00e01161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97

19  GraphicsServices                    0x0177b268 GSEventRunModal + 217

20  GraphicsServices                    0x0177b32d GSEventRun + 115

21  UIKit                               0x0035e42e UIApplicationMain + 1160

22  ShopMonkey                          0x000026d8 main + 102

23  ShopMonkey                          0x00002669 start + 53

)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://alkjdlkjaflkdjflakjdf"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSString *req;

    req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&pass=%@",userName,Password];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [req dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];

if (connection) {
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithLength:0]; // an ivar of type NSMutableData
} else {

    UIAlertView *failAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Could Not Connect" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [failAlert show];
}
```

Now use the follwing delegates to handle the request

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [receivedData appendData:data];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

receivedData = nil;

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error.localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    [self performSelector:@selector(getData:) withObject:receivedData afterDelay:0];

}
```

Now you have to parse the data you have in the getData function called above

```
-(void)getData:(NSData*)response{
NSError *erro;

SBJSON *parse                               =           [[SBJSON alloc]init]; 
// have to include SBJSON lib else you can use the inbuild NSJSONSerialization

NSString *jsonString                        =           [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response
                                                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

NSDictionary *jsonData                      =           [parse objectWithString:jsonString error:&erro];
NSArray *allEvents                          =           [jsonData objectForKey:@"Your_OBJECT"];

  if(![allEvents isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [allEvents count] > 0)
  {

 // now do what you want with the data   

  }
}
```

Comment: did you change the url with yours and and also added the parameter in req string and also added an ivar NSMutbaleData *receivedData to your controller

Comment: also in line [jsonData objectForKey:@"Your_OBJECT"]; in place of Your_OBJECT you have to replace it with that particular json key for which you want data

Answer (score 0):

for Key by value passing in JSON your should go in this direction ..

```
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username", @"password", @"preference", @"uid", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"accuser", @"accpass", @"abc_region", @"100", nil];
NSDictionary *theRequestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/request.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0f];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[theRequest setValue:@"application/json-rpc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *theBodyString = [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeDictionary:theRequestDictionary];
NSLog(@"%@", theBodyString);
NSData *theBodyData = [theBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// NSLog(@"%@", theBodyData);
[theRequest setHTTPBody:theBodyData];

NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
NSError *theError = NULL;
NSData *theResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
NSString *theResponseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(theResponseString);
NSDictionary *theResponseDictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserialize:theResponseString];
NSLog(@"%@", theResponseDictionary);
NSString *theGreeting = [theResponseDictionary objectForKey:@"greeting"];
[self setValue:theGreeting forKey:@"greeting"];
```

Just and check .. 
one more thing u will find this file **CJSONSerializer** from here 
[CJSONSerializer file path](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON)

.................

Comment: hi vivek i have tried ur suggestion but i am getting following error please refer my question i have updated the error details.

Comment: have u try this url passing parameter in it by appending behind like this "http://192.168.1.192/ShopMonkeyService/ShopMonkey.svc/Validate?username=admin&Password=111" .. check what response u getting .. because in log u getting null response ..

Comment: Thanks for the response The rest service will not allow URL Posting it should be done only through Making the Json data and posting the data only in HTTP Request Body. any help will be appreciated...

Comment: The same API is also accessed from Android there json response is successful only in iphone it did not work. Any update vivek?